# SQLite C# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I want to insert data into a database via sqlite but each time I got the error below:

Connection Established Successfully...

> code = Error (1), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
>   (0x800007BF): SQL logic error near "hpi_caseid": syntax error    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String
>   strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd,
>   CommandBehavior behave)    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn,
>   CommandDefinition& command, Action 2 paramReader)    at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition&
>   command)    at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql,
>   Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout,
>   Nullable 1 commandType)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.SqliteDataAccess.SaveCase(CaseModel CasesData) in
>   C:\Users\mansourm\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\SqliteDataAccess.cs:line
>   29    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.test() in
>   C:\Users\mansourm\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   249

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class SqliteDataAccess
    {
        public static void SaveCase(CaseModel CasesData)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO CasesData hpi_caseid VALUES @hpi_caseid", CasesData);
            }
        }

        private static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "Default")
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}



foreach (var c in ec.Entities)
{

    var newCase = new CaseModel();

    if (c.Attributes.Contains("hpi_caseid")) //Case ID
        newCase.hpi_caseid = Convert.ToInt64(c.Attributes["hpi_caseid"]);


    SqliteDataAccess.SaveCase(newCase);

}


public class CaseModel
{

    public long hpi_caseid;
}
```

//App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\mansourm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\hptest.db; Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

[image: Data Base screenshot]

I have tried with a relative path also but I got the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have missed the parenthesis after your table's name and after the `Values` keyword, i.e around `hpi_caseid` and `@hpi_caseid`:

```
cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO CasesData (hpi_caseid) VALUES (@hpi_caseid)", CasesData);
```

Also you have declared the parameter but didn't specify it's value, you need to specify a value something like this

```
yourCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@hpi_caseid", yourValue));
```

Comment: @Mehdi See my updated answer `INSERT INTO CasesData (hpi_caseid) VALUES (@hpi_caseid)`

Comment: @Mehdi You have declared the parameter but didn't specify it's value, you need to specify a value something like this `yourCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@hpi_caseid", yourValue));`